# How to read electron energy levels abbreviations?

Tags: quantum-chemistry

The electron energy transfer diagrams I've been coming across all have energy levels labeled as e.g. $^{2}F_{5/2}$ or $^{4}S_{3/2}$. I've tried to Google "quantum energy level abbreviations" but haven't come across anything too useful, just explanations of electron configurations. Can anyone explain or point to a website or textbook that goes through what these numbers/letters/fractions mean for someone who's taken general chemistry but not quantum mechanics?

Thanks!

Comment: It's a bit tough to understand where these numbers come from without QM, and I don't really want to write any technical inaccuracies (because this topic is confusing enough for QM students and having another sloppy account online won't help). However, as a general chemistry student, perhaps you are aware of the quantum numbers of an electron: $(n, l, m_l, m_s)$. $m_s$ has to do with the spin of the electron, which is an "intrinsic angular momentum" of the electron. $m_l$ has to do with the orbital the electron is in, which confers a certain amount of angular momentum on the electron as well.

Comment: ... If you add up the angular momenta of all the electrons in an atom, you can get the angular momentum of the atom. In short, then, the top-left number represents the spin angular momentum of an atom, the middle letter represents the orbital angular momentum of an atom, and the bottom-right number represents the total angular momentum of an atom, which is simply a sum of the previous two angular momenta.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those are *Russel Saunders atomic term symbols* and represent the quantum numbers of the many-electron wave function.

The notation scheme is $^{2S+1}L_J$ where $2S+1$ is the spin multiplicity, $L$ is the angular momentum quantum number and $J$ is the total angular momentum due to the coupling between the former two.

There are also *molecular term symbols* using greek instead of latin letters for the angular momentum. Those are commonly used for diatomic molecules.

You should find the *Russel Saunders Coupling scheme* in standard physical and quantum chemistry books. *Molecular term  symbols* are for example explained in detail in **Molecular Spectra and Molecular Structure: I. Spectra of Diatomic Molecules** by Herzberg and Huber (1950).
This link may give you a preliminary idea : http://wwwchem.uwimona.edu.jm/courses/RScoupling.html